# symfony2, behat and mink: accessing the container after redirect

Tags: symfony, behat, mink

I have a behat+mink scenario where a step visits a URL (mink), and the controller

- puts something into the a service in the container
- performs a redirect to another URL

The problem is that the controller redirect resets the container, so the service is re-constructed, and the following behat step cannot access it anymore

Is there a way to access the container ?

Answer (score 1):

In [CommonContexts](https://github.com/Behat/CommonContexts) there's a [MinkRedirectContext](https://github.com/Behat/CommonContexts/blob/master/Behat/CommonContexts/MinkRedirectContext.php). You can use it to prevent redirection. This way you'll be able to inspect container before the redirection is made.

Comment: it worked, great, thanks. I placed "And I do not follow redirects" as a step from that context